# Python > Getting stuck on Proceed to Checkout

Tags: python

New to Python.

Creating smoke test for Checkout process.

Am unable to click the Proceed to Checkout button.

On the Add-Ons page of the Checkout process, I am unable to click the Proceed to Checkout button which allows the user to go to the Attendee Info page of Checkout.

I've tried a few different things.  Below is the most basic attempt.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

username = 'bmendenhall@sans.org'
password = 'Lloydcole2!'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://www.sans.org/')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='Log In']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='regularsubmit']").click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.get('https://registration.sans.org/sans/s/cart/0a62J000000ClOsQAK')

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='proceed to checkout']").click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Error Messaging:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/BMendenhall/Desktop/Projects/sans-domain-testing/AddtoCartcontinue.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='proceed to checkout']").click()   File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {   File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[title='proceed to checkout']"}   (Session
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On the Add-Ons page of the Checkout process, I am unable to click the Proceed to Checkout button which allows the user to go to the Attendee Info page of Checkout.

Comment: put this explanation in question, not in comment.

Comment: do you get errror meesage? Show it in question (not in comments) as text.

Comment: it seems `CSS_SELECTOR` has problem even with `button[title]` but works for me `find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='proceed to checkout']")`

Comment: BTW: first I tested it with `find_elements` (with `s` at the end) and it finds two buttons with `'proceed to checkout'` - maybe this makes problem with CSS.

Comment: That is a huge help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but `CSS_SELECTOR` has problem even with `button[title]` but `XPATH` works for me

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title='proceed to checkout']")
```

---

BTW:

first I tested it with `find_elements` (with `s` at the end) and it finds two buttons with `'proceed to checkout'` - maybe this makes some problem with `CSS`.